# Using two date comparisons instead of date range query gives different results in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

With objects like this:

```
{
    "status" : 1,
    "date" : ISODate("2014-02-13T13:00:31.233Z")
}
```

Why does this range query

```
db.collection.find({
    "status": 1,
    "date": {
    $lte: ISODate("2015-06-16T20:05:03.000Z"),
    $gte: ISODate("2015-06-15T20:05:03.000Z")
    }
});
```

give the correct result while these two date comparisons give a different result:

```
db.collection.find({
    "status": 1,
    "date": {
    $lte: ISODate("2015-06-16T20:05:03.000Z")
    },
    "date": {
    $gte: ISODate("2015-06-15T20:05:03.000Z")
    }
});
```

It looks like the last query actually end up as an OR between the date comparisons, not AND as I would expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is not the same is because you are breaking a general rule of "hash/map" structures that applies to JavaScript Objects as well. That rule says that a "key" can only be specified **once**.

As such when you write:

```js
db.collection.find({
    "status": 1,
    "date": {
        "$lte": ISODate("2015-06-16T20:05:03.000Z")
    },
    // The next same key overwrites the other one
    "date": {
        "$gte": ISODate("2015-06-15T20:05:03.000Z")
    }
});
```

One of the `"date"` items there is "ignored" because there can only be one at each level. So effectively either the "less than" or "greater than" is being thrown away as a condition ( likely the "less than" since it is first ) and all documents are only being tested for a single condition.

Here's the solid example. Consider these documents:

```js
{ "a": 1 },
{ "a": 2 },
{ "a": 3 },
{ "a": 4 }
```

When you issue this query:

```js
 db.collection.find({ "a": { "$gte": 2 }, "a": { "$lte": 3 } },{ "_id": 0 })
```

The results come as only matching the "second" condition as that key overwrote the "first". It clearly violates the "first" condition, so that shows you it was "discarded":

```js
{ "a": 1 }
{ "a": 2 },
{ "a": 3 },
```

So in order to get **both** conditions applied you specify like you did earlier:

```js
db.collection.find({
    "status": 1,
    "date": {
        "$lte": ISODate("2015-06-16T20:05:03.000Z"),
        "$gte": ISODate("2015-06-15T20:05:03.000Z")
    }
});
```

Which is essentially "shorthand" for writing this:

```js
db.collection.find({
    "status": 1,
    "$and": [
        { "date": {
            "$lte": ISODate("2015-06-16T20:05:03.000Z")
        }},
        { "date": {
            "$gte": ISODate("2015-06-15T20:05:03.000Z")
        }}
    ]
});
```

Which is allowed since each element is in it's own document and a member of an array. The separation there allows you to use the same key names in each element.

Comment: Excellent answer, but also rather scary :) This may be a common error that could be difficult to find.

Answer (score 0):

`find({"status" : 1, "date":{ $lte:ISODate("2015-06-16T20:05:03.000Z")},"date":{$gte:ISODate("2015-06-15T20:05:03.000Z")}})`;

Here You are trying to find date(key) lessthan 2015-06-16T20:05:03.000Z and in same query you are ading date(key) with 2015-06-15T20:05:03.000Z.
You have only one key as date.

Above query behaves like select * from table where date >=2015-06-15T20:05:03.000Z and date <= 2015-06-15T20:05:03.000Z

But first query takes one date as key and takes multiple values for comparasion.

Comment: That's not quite the accurate description. Look closely at the document structure of the query and see what is wrong here. Hint: Something about "keys" and uniqueness of names.

Comment: Check what is there..then provide comment..Thanks

Comment: I did read what you supplied and it does not explain the reason why the two queries are different. I tried to give you a hint so you could change your answer but you seem to have ignored that or misunderstood.